# Shortcut to wrap text with latex macro (macOS, systemwide)

Tags: macros, keyboard, shortcut, macos

I'm looking for a way to create systemwide shortcuts on macOS to wrap selected text with some LaTeX macro (like {}, or \emph{}, but especially I'm interested in some creating some custom ones).

I know editors such as TeXShop do this, but I'd like to create a service, that I can then assign a shortcut to in the System Preferences, which wraps text in any application (at least the ones that use standard Mac text processing). 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: As that's basically a MacOS Services question not specific to TeX, this might get closed as off-topic. But [How To Create Your Own Services Menu Options on Mac](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-your-own-services-menus-mac/) at MakeUseOf looks like the way to go.

Comment: Hmm, Automator is of course a possibility, but I was hoping maybe someone already has a solution to this?

Comment: See this question, for a simple version of what you want: [How to create a service that puts selected text into quotation marks?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/229745)

Comment: @AlanMunn Didn't think that this was so easy! Thank you. Might it be worth to link this to the macos site for future reference?

Comment: @jan Since this might be useful for others here, it would be good if you posted an answer yourself showing how you did this for a few TeX related things.

Comment: The script @AlanMunn pointed to can be simplified quite a bit; see a remark I just added there. But note that if you run `sed -E`, you need to double any backslashes in the replacement string.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen -- why don't you post an answer citing your inspiration as the question/answer on the apple site.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'll give it some thought. I admit I had not read the question carefully enough; clearly, using `sed` is not appropriate for the present usage. For adding emphasis, something like `echo -n '\emph{'; cat; echo -n '}'` comes closer. However, Automator's “Run shell script” action adds a newline to the end of the text, and that seems tricky to remove with standard unix utilities. If I can think of a good way, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refer you to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229775) on the Apple Stack Exchange site for how to create a service which replaces text.

Instead of the `sed` script posted there, you can use the following to wrap `\emph{…}` around the text:

```
IFS='' echo -n '\emph{'"`cat`"'}'
```

Note the careful use of quotes: The single quotes in `'\emph{'` and `'}'` ensure that all characters within are taken literally, while the double quotes around the backquoted `cat` in the middle allow the backquotes to do their work. The initial `IFS=''` serves to tell `bash` not to split the text on spaces, tabs, and newlines.

If you need single quotes in the inserted text, a tricky construct is needed: Something like `'fo'\''c'\''sle'` will expand into `fo'c'sle`.

Comment: For some reason I don't quite understand, the simpler script `echo -n '\emph{'; cat; echo -n '}'` introduces an extra space before the final brace.