# Where to put my file of personal macros (TeXShop)

Tags: macros

I just got a new MacBook and downloaded TeXShop, and I have a file full of macros and stuff I want to put in the place where TeXShop looks for it so I can input it into every document without having a massive preamble. I successfully did this on my previous computer!

But now I can't figure it out again, and my googling is not giving useful results.

Specifically, I read that I need a folder in my Library called texmf/tex/latex and I should put my stuff in there.  When I do that, TeXShop tells me it can't find the file.

All advice appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: To start with, you don't need a big preamble to include from the same folder, and could move a few copies around as required (copy use delete) without having dozens of copies in every project. The macros if in a .tex file can be stored in a folder with the environment (alias) set for TEXINPUTS (so search that for MacOS OSX also your system or local (personal) texmf can be set once but beware while testing sometimes you need to log out & in to check it was set, look out for such comments. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423957/shortcut-to-wrap-text-with-latex-macro-macos-systemwide

Comment: You need to create the `texmf/tex/latex` tree in `~/Library`, the Library folder in you HOME folder, not `/Library`, the Library folder in the root of you HD. That Library folder is usually hidden. To open it hold the Option key down and click on the Go menu in Finder and a menu item to open that Library folderwill apear.

Comment: Thank you!  Logging out then back in did the trick!

Comment: I did discover that I needed to be careful with the choice of Library.  Good advice, thanks.